# Вывод данных в java через экспонету

Tags: java, вывод

Нужно вывести погрешность вычислений :

```
float a = 0.000012000
System.out.format("%f", a);
```

---

Как сделать, чтобы оно вывело 0.120е-4 ?

---

Мне нужно точность в 3 знака(первые 3 знака после 0)

---

```
float f = 0.0200123000f;

System.out.println(f);  //0.0200123 А надо 0.200е-1    

float f2 = 3.0200123000f;

System.out.println(f2);  //3.0200124  А надо 3.02е0 

float f3 = 0.0000123000f;

System.out.println(f3);//1.23E-5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать класс `Formatter`. Вот пример использования:

```
float f = 0.0200123000f;
System.out.println(String.format("%.3e", f)); // 2.001e-02

f = 3.0200123000f;
System.out.println(String.format("%.3e", f)); // 3.020e+00
```

Результат может зависеть от локали. Если у вас запятые вместо точек, то используйте другую локаль:

```
System.out.println(String.format(Locale.US, "%.3e", f));
```